# 401 error on local debug of ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, iis

I've got an ASP.NET 4.5.2 app that I wrote a couple months back with Visual Studio 2013.  I got a simple change request this morning, which I did in about 5 minutes.  I tried to debug it locally and it's giving me "HTTP Error 401.0 - Unauthorized".  I'm not sure what's changed because it debugged fine before.  Two hours of Google and trial-and-error, and still no luck.

I'm using IIS Express.  I see IIS Express running in my systray.  I can View Sites under IIS Express, and it gives me a directory listing.  I can navigate folders and open files that IIS recognizes.  If I try the .ASPX, I get the 401 again.

What do I have to do to fix this?

Comment: 1) Re-compile (do a full-build/compile of all of the existing projects). 2) Make sure you are accessing the right URL. 3) Make sure you are using the latest build versions.

Comment: 1. I did a Clean Solution & Rebuild Solution.  No change

Comment: Have you changed your password recently?

Comment: (I guess ENTER is not allowed /sigh)
2. F8 to Start Debugging connects to http://localhost:55045/main.aspx, which looks correct to me.
3. I assumed the debugger used the latest build.  How can I check what it's using?

Comment: George Johnston, you get a gold star!  Changed this morning.  I logged off afterwards, but not a full reboot.  I'll try that now.

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/2a924371-adca-4177-bb00-ff370f543b85/issue-with-local-debug-in-vs-2013-http-error-4010-unauthorized?forum=visualstudiogeneral

Comment: Sorry George Johnson, the reboot didn't change anything.

Comment: I completely deleted my local source and got it back from source control.  Still doing the same nonsense.